# What would be the most appropriate HTML element to encapsulate the word GET on an API instructional page?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm working on a page with some API instructions.  I make efforts to use proper HTML code, whenever possible, but I'm kind of stumped as to what to use for the word GET (as in this is a GET request, not a PUT request) in the instructions.  It isn't a big deal, but it does make me feel like I do my job just a bit better.

It's not something that the user types, so `<kbd>` doesn't really seem relevant.  `<samp>` doesn't seem to fit, either, as it's not something that would be output to the screen.  I considered `<code>`, but that just doesn't sit right.

A lot of the websites that give API instructions don't seem to care much about semantics.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the `code` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element):

> The code element represents a fragment of computer code. This could be an XML element name, a filename, a computer program, or any other string that a computer would recognize.

So `<code>` is the right element to represent an HTTP method (since that is a "string that a computer would recognize). You can even add a class.

```
<code class="http"><code class="method">GET</code> <code class="Request-URI URI">/</code> <code class="version">HTTP/1.1</code></code>
```

Comment: That works for me.  I always use `<code>` for actually chunks of code, but I guess it extends further than that.

Comment: The key is to remember that it is for *computer code* rather than *program code*.

Comment: The practical difference between `code`, `kbd`, `samp`, and `tt` is very small: they all cause the default font to be monospace, and little else. But `code` is admittedly the most logical choice. It may also have a marginal practical benefit over the alteratives: some automatic translation systems treat `code` content as untranslatable (which is good, since `GET` as an HTTP method name should not change in translation, of course).

Comment: Well, we don't choose the element based on what it displays like.  We choose it for what it means.  Knowledge about translation software is worthwhile, though.